# change bigint to string in Athena View

Tags: mysql, sql, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to change the datatype of one of my columns in Athena VIEW. It is currently set as `bigint` and when I try to join my view with another view, I get the following error: `'=' cannot be applied to varchar, bigint`. I need to convert `bigint` to `string`.
Tried the following:

```
ALTER VIEW db.my_view MODIFY COLUMN my_column varchar(50)
```

error message: `no viable alternative at input 'alter view'`

Comment: view are **not** tables!! edit the code of the view

Comment: I know views are not tables. The reason why I posted this question is that I can't find how to make this happen with the VIEW instead of table...

Answer (score 6):

```
Cast("db"."my_column" as varchar) as my_column
```

Comment: this was also a nice hack when you want to create a view column with a empty string as the content